# Crear busqueda por color PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero hacer que los usuarios de mi aplicación puedan realizar búsquedas de imágenes por color. Tengo una tabla de imágenes que guarda los colores en hexadecimal como tipo string.

```
+----+-----------------+---------------+
| id | name            | color         |
+----+-----------------+---------------+
|  1 | Orange and Blue | 0c6cab        |
|  2 | Black and White | dba27e        |
|  3 | Full Colors     | 7ba709        |
|  4 | RoG             | 970404        |
|  5 | Triangles       | 167694        |
+----+-----------------+---------------+
```

La búsqueda debe hacerse con colores similares al que seleccione el usuario ya que si se hace con el color exacto difícilmente se encontrarían muchos resultados. ¿Es posible hacer esto con hexadecimal o debo guardar los colores como otro tipo de dato?.

**EDICIÓN 1**

Por colores similares me refiero a que cuando el usuarios busque por ejemplo un color rojo, la consulta devuelva todos los colores de tonalidad roja que se encuentren el la tabla sin que coincidan exactamente con el color buscado.

Comment: A modo de poder plasmar que serían _"colores similares"_, ¿podrías [editar tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/54012/edit) y agregar ejemplos donde indiques colores similares y los resultados esperados?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tendrías que implementar un algoritmo de distancia. Por ejemplo, sea tu tabla de colores:

```
SELECT 1 as id, 'Orange and Blue' as name,'0c6cab' as color UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Black and White','dba27e' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Full Colors    ','7ba709' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'RoG            ','970404' UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Triangles      ','167694'
```

(que es lo que estabas mostrando)

Puedes separar cada número hexadecimal en su propio campo:

```
SELECT 
    colors.*, 
    LEFT(color,2) as R , 
    RIGHT(LEFT(color,4),2) as G, 
    RIGHT(color,2) as B 
FROM colors;
```

Lo que te daría:

```
+----+-----------------+-------------------------------+
| id | name            | color         |   R | G  | B  |
+----+-----------------+-------------------------------+
|  1 | Orange and Blue | 0c6cab        |  0c | 6c | ab |
|  2 | Black and White | dba27e        |  db | a2 | 7e |
|  3 | Full Colors     | 7ba709        |  7b | a7 | 09 |
|  4 | RoG             | 970404        |  97 | 04 | 04 |
|  5 | Triangles       | 167694        |  16 | 76 | 94 |
+----+-----------------+-------------------------------+
```

Ahora, puedes expresar esas columnas con su transformación a decimal:

```
SELECT 
    colors.*, 
    CONV(LEFT(color,2),16,10) as R , 
    CONV(RIGHT(LEFT(color,4),2),16,10) as G, 
    CONV(RIGHT(color,2),16,10) as B 
FROM colors;

+----+-----------------+--------------------------------+
| id | name            | color         |   R | G  | B   |
+----+-----------------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | Orange and Blue | 0c6cab        | 12  | 108 | 171|
|  2 | Black and White | dba27e        | 219 | 162 | 126|
|  3 | Full Colors     | 7ba709        | 123 | 167 |   9|
|  4 | RoG             | 970404        | 151 |   4 |   4|
|  5 | Triangles       | 167694        | 22  | 118 | 148|
+----+-----------------+--------------------------------+
```

La "distancia" de un color RGB (200,100,120) a cada uno de tus colores sería

```
distancia = sqrt( (200-R)² + (100-G)² + (120-B)² )
```

Esto sería mejor encapsularlo en una función que tome dos hexadecimales, los separe en RGB decimal y haga este cálculo, retornando la distancia.

Hecho lo anterior, sólo te queda filtrar la query a aquellos registros cuya distancia del color ingresado sea menor a tu margen de tolerancia.

Comment: Gracias @amenadiel, para comprobar la distancia tengo que hacer el bucle para verificar registro por registro?

Answer (score 0):

creo que asi como lo tienes esta bien y para hacer una consulta buscando los colores similares utilizas el operador LIKE, por ejemplo

Digamos que el usuario en #77 y tu en tu consulta haces esto:

```
  select color from color where color LIKE '%#77%'
```

la consulta te devoleria esto:

```
   +---------------+
   | color         |
   +---------------+
   | #777          |
   | #777777       |
   | #77797a       |
   | #778877       |
```

Comment: Quitando el # podría funcionar, pero habría falsos positivos, considerando que `aabbcc` sería similar a `ab`.